# How to convert datetime format to date format in crystal report using C#?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

i am working c# windows form application and also in crystal report.i am retriving the date from database in datetime format but i like display date only in report,Is any formula field in crystal report help for me for this problem.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In crystal report formulafield date function aavailable there pass your date-time format in that You Will get the Date only here

Example: `Date({MyTable.dte_QDate})`

Answer (score 33):

If the datetime is in field (not a formula) then you can format it:

1. Right click on the field -> Format Editor
2. Date and Time tab
3. Select date/time formatting you desire (or click customize)

If the datetime is in a formula:

```
ToText({MyDate}, "dd-MMM-yyyy")
//Displays 31-Jan-2010
```

or

```
ToText({MyDate}, "dd-MM-yyyy")
//Displays 31-01-2010
```

or

```
ToText({MyDate}, "dd-MM-yy")
//Displays 31-01-10
```

etc...

Comment: What about //Display 31 january ?

Answer (score 3):

In case the formatting needs to be done on Crystal Report side.

Simple way.

Crystal Report Design Window->Right click on the date field->format Field->Customize the date format per your need.

Works effectively.

Answer (score 2):

This formula works for me:

```
// Converts CR TimeDate format to AssignDate for WeightedAverageDate calculation.

Date( Year({DWN00500.BUDDT}), Month({DWN00500.BUDDT}), Day({DWN00500.BUDDT}) ) - CDate(1899, 12, 30)
```

Answer (score 1):

In selection formula try this

```
Date(Year({datetimefield}), Month({datetimefield}), Day({datetimefield}))
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is just a format issue use `ToShortDateString()`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the field is not recognized by crystal reports as DATE, so you can add a formula with function:
     Date({YourField}),
And add it to the report, now when you open the format object dialog you will find the date formatting options.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways you can do this. You can just use what is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(VS.71).aspx) or you can do `myDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");` There are plenty of help for this topic in the MSDN documentation.

You could also write you own DateExtension class which will allow you to go something like `myDate.ToMyDateFormat();`

```
    public static class DateTimeExtensions
    {
        public static DateTime ToMyDateFormat(this DateTime d)
        {
            return d.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        }
    }
```

Comment: The user asked specifically for Crystal Syntax; not c#