# how to convert Date to DateTime in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

how to convert Date to DateTime in crystal report

Here's the formula: help me please :(

```
if isnull({Command.DepartureDate}) then DateTime(0,0,0)

else

if ({Command.DepartureDate}='') THEN Date(0,0,0) 

ELSE 

Date(ToNumber(LEFT({Command.DepartureDate}, 4)),
      ToNumber(Mid ({Command.DepartureDate}, 6, 2)),
      ToNumber(Mid ({Command.DepartureDate}, 9, 2))
     )
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262464/how-to-convert-datetime-format-to-date-format-in-crystal-report-using-c

Comment: What is the issue with the formula?

Comment: the output is: 28-Dec-2014 12:00AM my Expected output is 28-Dec-2014 11:19AM why it is the time always at 12:00AM? whats wrong with the formula? :(

Comment: Thats a slightly strange requirement. What is the datatype of the Command.DepartureDate field? Isnt it datetime already? Then why convert? 12Am is the default time it is picking up. How will crystal know what time you are expecting.

Comment: Command.DepartureDate is string i want to convert it to DateTime using formula :(

Comment: first Command.DepartureDate is a string i want to convert it as DateTime instead of Date only.. what's locking in my formula?