# Convert Date String to Date Type

Tags: datetime, crystal-reports

How can I convert a string field formatted as `2017/09/08 00:00:00:00` to a date type that reads 09/08/2017?

Comment: Check @Nathan Koop's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262464/how-to-convert-datetime-format-to-date-format-in-crystal-report-using-c

Comment: This is not working for me, I receive an error "too many arguments have been given to this function"

Comment: can you write what you have tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, `DTStoDate{yourStringhere}` is the in-house solution.

Otherwise, filter out the blank time data by taking only the 10 leftmost characters of that string. Then cast it: `DateValue(Left({yourStringhere},10))`

Comment: Even better - I'll add that in for posterity.